# "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"

Tags: java

Hola soy nuevo en java y he hecho este codigo, pero en el token else me da el error de "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token", no se si alguien me pueda ayudar

Codigo:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGH)
public boolean onPlayerCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    Player sender = event.getPlayer();
    String mensaje = event.getMessage();
    String ip = event.getPlayer().getAddress().getHostName();
    if (event.getMessage().contentEquals("test"))
    if (event.getMessage().equals("/gamemode 1"))
    if (event.getMessage().equals("/gamemode 2"))
    if (event.getMessage().equals("/gamemode 3"))
    event.getPlayer().getAddress().getHostString();
    String ip1 = event.getPlayer().getAddress().getHostName();
    InetSocketAddress ipposta = event.getPlayer().getAddress();
    Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "ban " + event.getPlayer().getName());
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("paper security executed");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("beta"); {
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ip1 + "la ip del jugador es la mencionada, #papersecurity");
    Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "bc " + event.getPlayer().getAddress());
    return false;

    }else{
    event.setCancelled(true);
    return true; }
}

}
```

Comment: Debes tabular correctamente tu código. Haces una serie de IFS anidados sin llaves, por lo que la llave del else cierra el método onplayercommand. Creo que si añades una llave abierta en el if de gamemode3 se puede resolver tu problema

Comment: Por aquí además parece que hay una llave perdida `Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("beta"); {` Tabula el código, por favor y utiliza llaves en tus IFs

Comment: Aparte de lo que ya te han comentado, necesitas optimizar tu código y de paso queda más legible. En vez de llamar a cada rato a `event.getMessage()` es mejor almacenar el valor devuelto por `event.getMessage()`  en una variable y usarla para hacer las comparaciones. También es probable que tu código quede más claro con un `switch ... case` aunque no queda claro al final para qué son todos esos `if` que llevan al mismo bloque de código.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es simple, **tienes dos errores pero al solucionar el básico solucionas el derivado**:

1-El primero es que **como buena práctica de programación se recomienda que los " if(...) " siempre lleven llaves** y una de las razones es para evitar tu error.

```
If(...){
    Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
}else{
    Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
}
```

Pero Java también te permite hacer sentencias **sin llaves** del tipo:

```
If(...) 
    Una única línea de codigo;
else 
    Una única línea de código;
```

Ahora es cuando viene el problema. Si te encuentras con la siguiente situación como es tu caso:

```
If(...) 
    If(...)
        Una única línea de código;
```

Lo anterior sigue siendo perfectamente válido, pero el problema viene cuando añades un else:

```
If(...) 
    If(...)
        Una única línea de código;
    else {
      Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
     }
```

**ERROR:** El else en tiempo de compilación no se sabe a qué if tiene que ir asociado, ¿va al primero?, ¿va al segundo? ¿como lo identifica el compilador?. No puede.

CÓDIGO CORRECTO:

```
If(...){ 
    If(...){
        Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
    } else {
      Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
    }
}
```

Ó

```
If(...){ 
    If(...){
        Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
    }
} else {
      Una única línea de código o múltiples; ....
}
```

Es por esto que en estas situaciones tienes que poner llaves siempre para evitar el problema.

2-El segundo error es el cierre de llaves, la única llave que está abierta es la de `Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("beta"); {`  por lo que al cerrarla el compilador de Java detecta que no es una sentencia condicional y no admite el else al cerrar la llave.

```
Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("beta"); { 
   Código....; 
} else { 
    Código....; 
}
```

NO ES VALIDO.

Soluciona el error 1 y no tendrás que preocuparte por este.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Buena y completísima respuesta =).